# Como reemplazar contenido de un array por elementos de otro array JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una duda sobre si es posible, y en caso de que lo sea, cómo se puede reemplazar contenido de un array, por contenido de otro array.

**Por ejemplo:** 
**Entrada:** "azul rojo y verde"

`find = ["azul", "rojo", "verde", "y"]
replace = ["blue", "red", "green", "and"]
texto = texto.replace(find, replace)
return text`

**Salida:** "blue red and green"

Muchas gracias, y disculpen si formulé mal la pregunta, soy nuevo consultando en stackoverflow, pero en ocasiones me han insultado por no utilizar los elementos para separar código de consulta.

Comment: ¿Quieres reemplazar la totalidad del contenido del array? ¿O solo algunos elementos concretos?

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega el resultado esperado.

Comment: Disculpen, no sé si me explico bien, quiero que de un array de una lista de elementos que quiero que se encuentren en el "texto", para que sean reemplazados por otros elementos, no quiero reemplazar el array.

Comment: @EstebanFernández Perdona, pero sigo sin entenderte :S ¿Quieres modificar una palabra del array por otra? ¿Podrías **[edit]** tu pregunta y poner un ejemplo de la entrada y la salida que debería tener?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podrías usar:

- [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), para que por cada palabra del arreglo `find`, busques y reemplaces por la palabra en la misma posición dentro del arreglo `repalce`.
- *[OPCIONAL]* Si la intención es buscar y reemplazar la palabra exacta, entonces deberías usar la expresión regular:

  ```
  /\b(palabra)\b/
  ```

  De esta forma se evitaría errores al reemplazar palabras contenidas dentro de una palabra.

#### Demo sin RegExp

```js
function doIt() {
  let text = "azul rojo yellow y verde"
  let find = ["azul", "rojo", "verde", "y", "yellow"]
  let replace = ["blue", "red", "green", "and", "amarillo"]

  find.forEach((value, index) => {
    text = text.replace(new RegExp(value, 'g'), replace[index])
  })
  return text
}

console.log(doIt());
```

#### Demo con RegExp

```js
function doIt() {
  let text = "azul rojo yellow y verde"
  let find = ["azul", "rojo", "verde", "y", "yellow"]
  let replace = ["blue", "red", "green", "and", "amarillo"]

  find.forEach((value, index) => {
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('\\b(' + value + ')\\b', 'g'), replace[index])
  })
  return text
}

console.log(doIt());
```

Comment: Es justamente lo que quería saber, así que ahora sé para qué utilizar forEach y let. Gracias

Comment: Me dí cuenta, gracias por los aportes